# ¿Como eliminar espacio en los bordes con bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy intentando hacer un login con `bootstrap` y me surgió un problema con los bordes, cuando intento insertar un borde en el formulario se agrega un espacio adicional y se solapa la cabecera de mi formulario, adjunto la imagen para mejor claridad.

[image: Formulario]

Entonces la cabecera del formulario queda con ese espacio en blanco, como podría eliminar ese espacio. Adjunto el `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=es>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!--Font to google -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Chettan" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Link para acceder a bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="xxx", filename="xxx")}}">
    <!--Link para acceder a bootstrap-->
    <!--Accede a los estilos css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for("xxx", filename = "xxx")}}">
    <!--Accede a los estilos css-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="container login-form">
    <form action="index.html" method="post" id="test" role=login>
      <div id="FormTop" class="form-group">
        <p>Login</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required class="form-control input-lg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control input-lg" />
                </div>
            </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success">SIGN IN</button>
      </div>
      <section>
        Not a member? <a href="#">Sign up now <span>&rarr;</span></a>
      </section>
    </form>
  </section>



  <!--scripts for that bootstrap work fine-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{url_for("xxx", filename="xxx")}}">

  </script>
  <!--scripts for that bootstrap work fine-->
  </body>
</html>
```

A continuación adjunto el `css`

```css
@charset "charset-name";

/* body configuration*/

*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;  /* linea que se dibuja en los*/
}

body{
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    font-family: 'Baloo Chettan', cursive;

}

/******************************Formulario*******************************************/
/*Cuadro de formulario*/

form[role=login]{
  margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  max-width: 400px;
    background-color:white;

}


/*Se configura los elementos relativos dentro del formulario*/

form[role=loging] div {
  position: relative;
}

/*Top of form with login*/
#FormTop
{
    background: #3498DB;
    text-align:center;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width:thin;
    border-collapse: none;
}


form[role=login]{
    border-collapse: none;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;

}
/*Se da tamao a los input y button y otras config*/
form[role=login] input,
form[role=login] button {
  font-size:14px;

}

/* se configura el color del icono a lado del input*/
form[role=login] .input-group-addon {
        background: #3498DB;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
}


/*se configura el button */


form[role=login] button {
        background: #3498DB;
        border: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        border-radius: 2px;

}



/**************************************************************************/

/*hack to generate minus space*/
.form-group {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
    .form-group input,
    .form-group .input-group-addon {
        border-radius: 2px;
}

form[role=login] > section {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
        form[role=login] > section span {
            color: #767a7f;

        }
```

Entonces, si quito el borde aplicado, vuelve a la normalidad, pero cuando lo inserto vuelve a tomar un espacio. Alguien que tenga habilidades en bootstrap que me pueda colaborar por favor se los agradezco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase `.form-group` tiene márgenes superior e inferior por lo que tendrías que eliminar ese margen en el div `#FormTop`. Cuando no tienes borde ese margen no se ve porque colapsan los margenes de ese div y el formulario pero al poner un borde hace de separador y cada elemento mantiene sus propios márgenes.
Lo dicho, si le pones un `margin:0` a `#FormTop` lo solucionas:

```css
/* body configuration*/

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  /* linea que se dibuja en los*/
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  font-family: 'Baloo Chettan', cursive;
}


/******************************Formulario*******************************************/


/*Cuadro de formulario*/

form[role=login] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: white;
}


/*Se configura los elementos relativos dentro del formulario*/

form[role=loging] div {
  position: relative;
}


/*Top of form with login*/

#FormTop {
  background: #3498DB;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: thin;
  border-collapse: none;
  margin:0;

}

form[role=login] {
  border-collapse: none;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

/*Se da tamao a los input y button y otras config*/

form[role=login] input,
form[role=login] button {
  font-size: 14px;
}


/* se configura el color del icono a lado del input*/

form[role=login] .input-group-addon {
  background: #3498DB;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}


/*se configura el button */

form[role=login] button {
  background: #3498DB;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}


/**************************************************************************/


/*hack to generate minus space*/

.form-group {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.form-group input,
.form-group .input-group-addon {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

form[role=login] > section {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

form[role=login] > section span {
  color: #767a7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container login-form">
  <form action="index.html" method="post" id="test" role=login>
    <div id="FormTop" class="form-group">
      <p>Login</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required class="form-control input-lg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></div>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required class="form-control input-lg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" name="go" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success">SIGN IN</button>
    </div>
    <section>
      Not a member? <a href="#">Sign up now <span>&rarr;</span></a>
    </section>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedo claro lo de la clase .form-group, no sabía que tenía margen.